# Spark submit not working on EMR - Failing Oozie Launcher, Attempt to add apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar multiple times to the distributed cache

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, oozie, emr, hue

I just provisioned EMR cluster with spark, oozie, hue insatlled. I am running the spark action in oozie in yarn-cluster mode. I am getting the following error:

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain], main() threw exception, Attempt to add (hdfs:namenodeec2:8020/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20170330151923/oozie/apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar) multiple times to the distributed cache.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attempt to add (hdfs://namenodeec2/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20170330151923/oozie/apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar) multiple times to the distributed cache.
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$11$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(Client.scala:608)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$11$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(Client.scala:599)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArraySeq.foreach(ArraySeq.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$11.apply(Client.scala:599)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$11.apply(Client.scala:598)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.prepareLocalResources(Client.scala:598)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.createContainerLaunchContext(Client.scala:868)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:170)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1154)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:1213)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:738)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain.runSpark(SparkMain.java:338)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain.run(SparkMain.java:257)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:60)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain.main(SparkMain.java:78)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:232)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:455)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:344)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalContainerLauncher$EventHandler.runSubtask(LocalContainerLauncher.java:380)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalContainerLauncher$EventHandler.runTask(LocalContainerLauncher.java:301)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalContainerLauncher$EventHandler.access$200(LocalContainerLauncher.java:187)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalContainerLauncher$EventHandler$1.run(LocalContainerLauncher.java:230)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this issue a couple of times before and seems like AWS folks still haven't fixed this. This problem according to AWS support guys arises with EMR version 5.3. However if you downgrade your EMR to version 5.1 this issue will be resolved.

Comment: I am on EMR 5.4 with Spark 2.0.1. Spark action worked just fine on EMR 5.1. The only probelm is I want to work on SPark 2.1 which is only available on EMR 5.3 or 5.4. I hope AWS looks into this weird issue